# I can't copy and paste underscore

Tags: pdf, font-encodings, copy-paste, underscore, lmodern

I have a problem that I have not been able to solve. When I generate my PDF document and want to copy the text to a terminal or a WORD document, the underscores are not copied. In the PDF it does print the underscores (Adobe Acrobat Reader, Foxit Reader) but when I want to copy it from the PDF to another place an empty space appears. I use `_`, I have also tried `\textunderscore`. Also, I am using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{lmodern}`. (I have seen that it was solved with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` but it doesn't work for me.) Could you help me?

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % landscape pages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Previene advertencias sobre fuentes no disponibles
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} % Configura los márgenes de página
%\usepackage{lineno} %Numeros en las lineas
%\linenumbers
%Paquete para incluir hipervínculos
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, 
linkcolor = black,
urlcolor  = blue,
citecolor = black,
anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} %Configura los titulos de las figuras y las tablas en negrita.
\usepackage{datetime}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%Paquete para el manejo de las unidades en el Sistema Internacional
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{mode=text, output-decimal-marker = {,}, per-mode = symbol, qualifier-mode = phrase, qualifier-phrase = { de }, list-units = brackets, range-units = brackets, range-phrase = --}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \atmosphere{atm}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \pound{lb}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \inch{"}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \foot{ft}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \yard{yd}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \mile{mi}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \pint{pt}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \quart{qt}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \flounce{fl-oz}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \ounce{oz}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \degreeFahrenheit{\SIUnitSymbolDegree F}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \degreeRankine{\SIUnitSymbolDegree R}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \usgallon{galón}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \uma{uma}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \ppm{ppm}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \eqg{eq-g}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \normal{\eqg\per\liter\of{solución}}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \molal{\mole\per\kilo\gram\of{solvente}}
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}} %Cambia el nombre de cuadros a 
%tablas
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue ...

Comment: In other words, delete all of the preamble that isn't related, and add in `\begin{document} text_with_underscore \end{document}`.  You should only need 10 lines of code.

Comment: But be forewarned, copy/paste from a pdf is a difficult task.  There are many questions on this site along those lines.

Comment: I do not see that issue, but I do not have `Sweave.sty` can you show the problem without that package (in general remove all packages from the example that are not needed to show the problem)